# If Timer reaches 60 Seconds, then an AlertView has to pop up

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uialertview, nstimer

I need to trigger an Alert after 60 seconds… My method, which you can find below, doesn't work… Please help.
ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender
{
    [self StartGame];
}

-(void) alertus
{
     Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"GAME OVER" message:@"Thank you for Playing!" >delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

}

-(void)startGame
{
  Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(TimmerCount) >userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    _START.hidden = TRUE;

    Timmer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(Alertus) >userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)timmerCount{
   Countnumber = Countnumber + 1;
   TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",Countnumber];
```

or i tried something like that
instead of Timmer2 i wrote

```
_START.hidden = TRUE;

if (Countnumber>=60) {
    [self Alertus];

}
```

but it didn't work either…………
Please Help! Thank you very much :-)

Julian E.

Comment: Please, try to name your method/var starting with a lower case. A `NSTimer` isn't a `"int"` value, it's an object, so you can't compare with `==60`. You better check this:`(countNumber>=60)`

Comment: doesn't work…… Still. I tried to exchange it, nothing happened at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show the alert. Add `[Alert show];` after initializing your alert.

Edit:

Other than the fact that you left out `[Alert show]` from your code, you need to force `Timmer2` to run on the current run loop after its initialization in order to make changes to the UI, ex.

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:Timmer2 forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

[Here's a better explanation of why than I could provide.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955918/2274694)

And another good post on this topic: [NSTimer not firing when runloop is blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995825/nstimer-not-firing-when-runloop-is-blocked)

Comment: where to add it? I added it to Alertus, didn't work. 
when I added it to the if statement,still din't work…

Comment: Yes, in alerts underneath the line of code already there. Why do you have ">" symbol throughout your code? Shouldn't be in any of the places where you have it written...

Comment: Oh, my bad… That was just formatting for Stackoverflow…. So what can i do @ Lyndsey Scott? It doesn't work under Alertus...

Comment: The action method of a timer is called on the *same thread* that was used to create the timer (in this case, the main thread).

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I updated my answer... Still working to iron out the explanation though. But I do think this code is the proper solution...

Comment: @LyndseyScott: You can start multiple timers from the main thread using `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` and they won't block each other.

Comment: @MartinR I mentioned the timer, but I also said "any other actions running on your main thread." Maybe I should leave out the bit about the 2nd timer. I'm assuming though that since it's a game, the user may be manipulating the UI and blocking the run loop in doing so...

Comment: @user3527280 Could I see your latest code? Chat should be enabled soon since we've posted a lot of comments... Just reply to this message.

Comment: @user3527280: Are the timer functions (alertus, timmercount) called at all?

Comment: It looks like there's a case-sensitivity mismatch when alertus and timmercount are called within the NSTimers... but it could just be a typo... I'd like to see the latest code.

Comment: @LyndseyScott How do you activate chat?

Comment: @user3527280 It's really annoying actually... Chat isn't activated until there are enough comments. I guess there still aren't enough... Is your TimerDisplay label updating properly at least?

Comment: @LyndseyScott how will it be activated? How will it look like?

Comment: It's not activated yet. It'll show up near the comment box. Maybe they removed the feature...

Comment: But is your TimerDisplay updating properly every second?

Comment: I'd like to know if your other timer is firing properly... Is your TimerDisplay updating as expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender
{
Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(TimerCount) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
_STARTBUTTON.hidden = TRUE;
Timmer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(Alertus) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}


-(void) Alertus
 {

// The Actual Alert
Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"GAME OVER" message:@"Thank you for Playing!"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

_
```

// Above the Setup the Alert

```
[Alert show];
[Timer invalidate];
Timer = nil;
```

}

I checked in a project in my own and everything runs perfectly. If you connect everything up, then after 30 seconds the Pop Up goes off, having a Dismiss button. It looks pretty nice! I hope that helped you!
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

i guess you missed to show the alert.
add

```
[Alert show];
```

Use the following code

## define kTimeInSeconds 1

```
 NSTimer *myTimer;
 myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: kTimeInSeconds 
                                   target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(handleTimer:) 
                                   userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];


-(void)handleTimer: (id) sender 
{       
 UIAlertView * Alert =   [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"GAME OVER" message:@"Thank you for Playing!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[Alert show];
}

-(void)stopTimer: (id) sender 
{       
   if(myTimer)
   {
       [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: i think u have not implemented handleTimer method

Comment: No i copied the exact code as you have written and the error described above comes at -(void) HandleTimer: (Id) Sender

Comment: -(void)StartGame

{
    NSTimer *myTimer; myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
-(void)handleTimer: (id) sender {
        [ [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"GAME OVER" message:@"Thank you for Playing!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil] show]; }
    
-(void)stopTimer: (id) sender {
        if(myTimer) { [myTimer invalidate]; myTimer = nil; } }}

-(void)TimmerCount{
Countnumber = Countnumber + 1;
TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",Countnumber];
}

Comment: check NSTimer example http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/timer-example-using-nstimer/  and UIAlertView example http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-build-your-first-iphone-app/